# Why ios6 destroys my View

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios7

i build a View with ios7 programamtically and everythings works just fine. But then i tested it with ios 6 and half of the View is broken and i don´t know why. I do not use any "ios7 only" things!!

Screenshot from ios7 (everything is fine):
[image]

Screenshot from ios6 (strange things happen here):

[image]

It is the same Code, UITextViews,UILabels and one UISegmentedControl. Any Ideas??

Comment: It looks like the label backgrounds are not set properly under iOS 6.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your text isn't showing up in iOS6 because it's white text on a white background. In iOS6, UILabel backgrounds are white by default, whereas they are clear by default in iOS7; so you have to explicitly set the label's background color to clear in order to account for both cases.

Comment: It looks like you beat me to it by 30 seconds ;)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like in iOS 6 your UILabels background color is defaulting to white.

Try this:

```
[myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```